# Preventing/Avoiding a Core Dump?

Tags: security

A core dump is a security problem, but I don't see any literature on how to deal with it.

The solution, I guess, is to use "Structured Exception Handling" to catch all exceptions/signals and deal with them or preemptively empty the memory if they're fatal?

Is there some setting I can affect to disable core dumps?

On a Windows desktop platform, primarily, but I'd like to know if there's a Linux solution as well.

Comment: Are core dumps caused by uncaught exceptions? I thought they were caused by signals.

Comment: On *nix they're signals, Windows calls them "Structured Exceptions", I believe

Comment: I think you can just write correct code and it won't dump core...

Answer (score 1):

On Linux, I believe you can just use the following:

```
ulimit -c 0
```

See e.g. http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/ulimit/.

Comment: Absolutely right. That reminded me of something I read in "Building Secure Software" (Viega & McGraw), turns out it's right there in Chapter 12. Programmatically you use `setrlimit(RLIMIT_CORE, &rlimStruct)`. Serves me right for skimming, I guess.

Comment: Any idea for Windows? I don't see any equivalent call.

Comment: @SamPorch: sorry, I don't know Windows programming ;)